# Is it possible get QT creator to automatically add variables to the .pro file

Tags: c++, qt

I've now started to dabble with QT and I was wondering if there was a way to get QT creator to automatically add variables to the project file. For example, I usually use C++11 code so it would be nice if QT could put CONFIG += c++11 in the .pro file automatically when I start a new project. I looked around in the options but I can't make sense of some sections so maybe it's right in front of my face?

Comment: If i remember correctly the templates should be located in ``\Tools\QtCreator\share\qtcreator\templates``

Comment: On OS X, it's in `$HOME$/Qt5.2.1/Qt Creator.app/Contents/Resources/templates`

Comment: @SebastianLange In the case of a Qt console application, is there a .pro file template? I searched everywhere to find a similar one and eventually edited all the .pro files in the templates folder but it didnt work for the Qt console application project type. It worked for some of the other project types though. I'm using Qt 5.1.1 on Windows.

Comment: @DanielJG Look at `templates\wizards` folder. There are many examples there. The readme file tells you how to change the .xml file names to have them recognized by Qt Creator (after a restart). You can, pretty much, create your own wizards, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the wizard files of Qt Creator. The files are in the following directory:

```
Qt-Dir/Tools/QtCreator/share/qtcreator/templates/wizards/
```

If you look at the directory there are some folders related to different wizards. For example if you look in to the "plaincppapp/qmake" folder, there you can see a "project.pro" file which is a template pro file. You can just edit that file like:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

CONFIG += C++11  #added this line

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Next time you create a project by that wizard, your custom pro would be created for the project.